# Creating a new variable to measure flatlining in other variables

Tags: stata, frequency, generate, likert

I am trying to analyze how extreme flatlining can be in a set of Likert-scale variables (V21-V34, V84-V92, and V114-V119). For example, if a respondent answers "strongly agree" for 14 out of 27 variables, "somewhat agree" for 9, "neither/nor" for 2, "somewhat disagree" for 1, and "strongly disagree" for 2, I would like this variable to be "14" for this respondent.

I don't have any code because I don't know where to begin here. I haven't had much experience with Stata.

EDIT: It seems like `egen` will work best for what I need. Code included below--

```
egen flatlinerstrongsupp = anycount(V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V84 V85 V86 V87 V88 V89 V90 V91 V92 V114 V115 V116 V117 V118 V119), values(1)
```

Comment: Can you provide data set (using `dataex`) that shows a simplified example with fever likert variables and manually input the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want the frequency of the mode for each person. Supposing that your possible values run 1 to 5, then this should help:

```
forval j = 1/5 { 
    egen count`j' = anycount(V21-V34 V84-V92 V114-V119), values(`j') 
} 
egen countmode = rowmax(count?)
```